# Angular UI-Bootstrap carousel not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to make a carousel using angular and Bootstrap but it simply doesn't work. I can't see the carousel at all and I see angular's brackett.

In other words, my result is:

Hi {{name}} Those are your photos:
Slide {{$index+1}}

This is my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.1.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        Write your name here <input type="text" ng-model="name">
        Hi {{name}} Those are your photos:  
        <div ng-controller="CarouselDemoCtrl" id="slides_control">
            <div>
                <uib-carousel interval="myInterval">
                    <uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="active" index="$index">
                        <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h4>Slide {{$index+1}}</h4>
                        </div>
                    </uib-slide>
                </uib-carousel>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my javascript script.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
myApp.controller('CarouselDemoCtrl', CarouselDemoCtrl);
function CarouselDemoCtrl($scope){
    $scope.myInterval = 3000;
    $scope.slides = [
                     {
                       image: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/'
                     },
                     {
                       image: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food'
                     },
                     {
                       image: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports'
                     },
                     {
                       image: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/people'
                     }
                   ];
});
```

**EDIT** I changed the codes above according to what the answer below says. It still doesn't work

Comment: You never actually define a controller. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Comment: You already have this example working in a codepen as a first  result of Google  http://codepen.io/Fabiano/pen/LACzk  you copy pasted some where and it is not working

Comment: as str said update your code with app.controller('CarouselDemoCtrl', CarouselDemoCtrl); before function

Comment: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel use appropriate directives

Comment: To answer N.V.Prasad, That link is exactly where I took it from. I don't understand why it doesn't work on me

Answer (score 3):

You can see a working sample in plunker link below.

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/mjXtFt9drbmwPFQG3f9i?p=preview)

```
<uib-carousel interval="myInterval">
    <uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="active" index="$index">
         <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
               <h4>Slide {{$index+1}}</h4>
          </div>
    </uib-slide>
</uib-carousel>
```

You are using the incorrect directives for the angular-ui.

Also, you are not defining the controller properly:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('CarouselDemoCtrl', CarouselDemoCtrl);
```

**UPDATE**

Complete working sample, even saved as a html file on your system.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.1.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">    
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('CarouselDemoCtrl', CarouselDemoCtrl);

function CarouselDemoCtrl($scope){
  $scope.myInterval = 3000;
  $scope.noWrapSlides = false;
  $scope.activeSlide = 0;
  $scope.slides = [
    {
      image: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/'
    },
    {
      image: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food'
    },
    {
      image: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports'
    },
    {
      image: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/people'
    }
  ];
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    Write your name here <input type="text" ng-model="name">
    Hi {{name}} Those are your photos:  
    <div ng-controller="CarouselDemoCtrl" id="slides_control">
        <div>
            <uib-carousel interval="myInterval" active="activeSlide">
                <uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" index="$index">
                    <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h4>Slide {{$index+1}}</h4>
                    </div>
                </uib-slide>
            </uib-carousel>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I changed the code (See the question above) but it still doesn't work

Comment: Are you getting any java script errors? Can you replicate it in a plunker? Also try to add the `$scope.active=0` in the controller. And the `ng-controller` should be set on the parent `div` to correctly work. It works because Angular tries to match the property by going up until the `rootview`.

Comment: Ok. I replicate it in a plunker and it works... So what may be the problem?

Comment: There may be a number of reasons. You need to say how are you hosing the page, and if there are any errors in console.

Comment: I just have a question: in my script I already had  var routingApp=angular.module('routingApp',['ngRoute']); because I need ngRoute; now I also need ui.bootstrap; is it possible to define them both?

Comment: Yes, the second parameter of the module function is an array. So, you can do it like this `angular.module('routingApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);`

Comment: Can you show a plunker? Because it should work fine.

Comment: Have you included the reference for angular route? It'a a different library.Updated [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/mjXtFt9drbmwPFQG3f9i?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Problem Is in your html..

```
<div>
    Write your name here <input type="text" ng-model="name">
    Hi {{name}} Those are your photos:  
    <div ng-controller="CarouselDemoCtrl" id="slides_control">
        <div style="height:500px;">
            <div uib-carousel interval="myInterval" active="activeSlide">
                <div uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" index="$index">
                    <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h4>Slide {{$index+1}}</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Use This Code Instead.