# AngularJS : Bootstrap Carousel showing all images at once in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add a carousel. But, All images are showing at once. I've tried this.

```
<div ng-controller="CarouselDemoCtrl">
  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators" ng-repeat="slide in slides">
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="$index" ng-class="{active: $index}"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item" ng-class="{active:$index}" ng-repeat="slide in slides">
        <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}?{{$index}}" style="margin:auto;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XxPzW/125/

Any suggestion please?

**Edit :**

Actually I am trying to play a video by clicking on play button. For that I need index of **carousel**. So that I can play video. But here the play button is outside the **ng-repeat**. How can I get index of Carousel.

**Fiddle :**  http://jsfiddle.net/XxPzW/131/

Comment: I suggest you to use [Angular UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) Carousal to avoid such issues.

Comment: @Shreyas He is using Angular UI bootstrap only.

Comment: @PirateX I don't see any `<uib-carousal>` directive.

Comment: here is an working example of carousel ,http://plnkr.co/edit/hVWvFXxpsm9jltUjAt7w?p=preview

Comment: @Shreyas Yep. Correct. I was checking th JS dependecy `angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);` which was already there.

Comment: [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35772414/angular-ui-bootstrap-carousel-not-working/35772695). This should help

Answer (score 1):

here is your modified [working code](http://jsfiddle.net/hff4m41k/)

You need to use Interval for updating images after certain time.

```
<div ng-controller="CarouselDemoCtrl">
  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" ng-repeat="slide in slides" data-slide-to="$index" ng-class="{active:isActive($index)}"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div >
      <div class="item" ng-class="{active:index}">
        <img src="{{currentImage.image}}?{{index}" style="margin:auto;">
        {{currentImage.text}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


var myApp = {};
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate'])

app.controller('CarouselDemoCtrl', ['$scope', '$animate', '$interval', function($scope, $animate, $interval) {

  // will work as normal, if globaly disabled
  $animate.enabled(true);

  $scope.slides = [{
    image: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/',
    text: 'blah1'
  }, {
    image: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature',
    text: 'blah2'
  }, {
    image: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food',
    text: 'blah3'
  }, ];

    $scope.isActive = function (i){
    return $scope.index-1 == i;
  }
  $scope.index = 0;
  $scope.currentImage = $scope.slides[$scope.index];

    $scope.updateImage = function (){
    $scope.currentImage = $scope.slides[ $scope.index];
    $scope.index++;
    if($scope.index >= $scope.slides.length ){
        $scope.index = 0
    }
  }

  $interval($scope.updateImage, 2000);

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/8c6UG/45/)

angularjs

```
angular.module('MyDemo', ['angular-carousel'])
.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.slideIndex = 0;

});
```

html

```
<div ng-app="MyDemo">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul rn-carousel rn-carousel-indicator rn-carousel-index="slideIndex" class="carousel-ui">
         <img ng-src="https://c7.staticflickr.com/3/2538/3742771246_2648fa4e6e_b.jpg" style="margin:auto;">
         <img ng-src="https://c7.staticflickr.com/3/2538/3742771246_2648fa4e6e_b.jpg" style="margin:auto;">
         <img ng-src="https://c7.staticflickr.com/3/2538/3742771246_2648fa4e6e_b.jpg" style="margin:auto;">
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

slide buttons display below fiddle result